# Django Static File Issue on Deployment

Tags: django, django-templates

Hello i'm trying to deploy a django app which uses the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` tag.

When I put my code up on EC2 (in debug mode) I get the following error:

```
Module "django.core.context_processors" does not define a "static" callable 
        request processor
```

This doesn't happen on `./manage.py` runserver
This also disapears when I remove the `django.core.context_processors.static` from my template context processors (but then I don't get static media)

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `static` context_processor - and the staticfiles app - were added in version 1.3. It looks like you're running an older version in production.

Comment: Does that mean I cannot use STATIC_URL in settings.py ?

Answer (score 1):

See also: http://blog.madpython.com/2010/04/07/django-context-processors-best-practice/

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found a solution. But since no one decided to put one here I will, In the event any one new to Django such as myself stumble upon this error, here is my solution. If you carefully read the error assuming you have DEBUG=True you will come to realise that the **static** definition(pythonic function) is missing from **context_processors.py** in the django.core module. Therefore head there in your directory. on my server it was **/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core**. Edit the context_processors.py and add the following function

```
 def static(request):
    # this func will static-related context variables to the context
    return {'STATIC_URL': settings.STATIC_URL}
```